# Hitting probability and recurrent Brownian motion

Tags: probability, reference-request, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, potential-theory

Consider a Brownian particle $B(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ starting at the origin, and let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. For a positive real number $\tau$, define
$$
P_1(\tau) = \text{ probability that } B(\tau) \in U,
$$
and
$$
P_2(\tau) = \text{ probability that } B(t) \in U \text{ for some } t \leq \tau.
$$
Clearly, one has that $P_1(\tau) \leq P_2(\tau)$ by simple inclusion.

My question is, if in addition one assumes that the motion is recurrent (as on the plane), do we also have some comparability relation like
$$
P_2(\tau) \leq c P_1(\tau),
$$
where $c$ is a constant independent of $\tau$? Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Additional remark: one can easily get comparability upto constants dependent on $\tau$, but this does not require recurrence. For the question above, it seems not so difficult to (naively!) believe that a comparability may hold if $\tau \geq \text{dist}(0, U)^2$.

Comment: Are you going to allow $c$ to depend on $U$?  Otherwise consider $U$ being the complement of the closed disk radius $1$ centred at the origin:  $P_1(\tau) \to 1$ and $P_2(\tau) \to 1$ as $\tau$ increases so you cannot do better than $c=1$

Comment: @Henry You are absolutely right. For large $\tau$, these two quantities are very close. So there must be some regime of $\tau$ where $P_1$ starts satisfying $P_1 \geq \frac{1}{2}P_2$. I was wondering whether that regime is $\tau \approx c_1\text{dist}(0, U)^2$ for some constant $c_1$.

Comment: What if $U$ is an extremely thin annulus centered at 0?  Then $P_2(\tau) \to 1$ but $P_1(\tau)$ is always small and approaches 0.

Comment: My earlier comment came from reading too fast: I had thought the question was about $P_1(\tau) \leq c P_2(\tau)$.  With the question as asked @NateEldredge's example seems to show there is no satisfactory $c$